# Five-point Function with five numerator terms

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, computational-physics, feynman-diagrams, software

I need to calculate the 1-Loop integral
$$\int d^D q \frac{q_{\mu_1}q_{\mu_2}q_{\mu_3}q_{\mu_4}q_{\mu_5}}{((q-p_1)^2-m_1^2)((q-p_1)^2-m_2^2)^2((q-p_1)^2-m_2^2)(q^2-m_3^2)((q-p_2)^2-m_4^2)},$$

where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are external momenta. I tried to do this calculation with LoopTools, but while LoopTools has 5-point functions implemented, it does not seem to have all the Lorentz compositions needed. I would need coefficients up to "ee44444", but for some reason LoopTools does not give all coefficients for the 5-point functions. I checked in their code, and the variables for these coefficients are not defined. Weirdly, for the 4-point function, coefficients up to dd33333 are defined.

Is there another program which can calculate these integrals, and if not, is there a smart way to do it by hand? I tried by hand and it is so lengthy.

I have already calculated it with Cutkosky rules and a dispersion relation, but I need to confirm my result with a non-dispersive calculation.

Comment: In how many spacetime dimensions?

Comment: Oh, I just saw the integral did not have them. I use dimensional regularization, so D-dimensional but later 4-2$\epsilon$

Comment: As much of this is highly localized to LoopTools, might it be beneficial to ask the authors of that module/package instead?